# I am trying to run this chain of effects but it doesn't work. Syntax is right but method is wrong?

Tags: jquery, queue, delay, nested

I have tried this a few ways with varying degrees of success but it always seems to break down somewhere what am i doing wrong here? Using setTimout seems too messy to me i am sure there is a nice way to do this in jQuery. Really appreciate any help with this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitme').click(function() {

        $('#submitme').fadeOut(500, function() {

            $('#progress').delay(500).fadeIn(500, function() {

                $('#progress .meter').delay(500).animate({width : '100%'},2000, function() {

                    $('#progress').delay(500).fadeOut(500, function() {

                        $('.alert-box').delay(500).fadeIn(500);

                    });

                });

            });

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Could you put your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ for demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

From the name of element where you attaching event handler I infer that it is submit button. If it is so - you need to pass `event` to your click handler and call `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$('#submitme').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //then your code
     $('#submitme').fadeOut(500,.....
    });
```

Also you can break your code on several different functions and use queue method to chain animations:

```
function animateProgress(){
   $('#progress').delay(500)
                 .fadeIn(500)
                 .queue(/*next callback function*/);
}

function animateSubmitMe(){
    $('#submitme').fadeOut(500)
                  .queue(animateProgress);
}

animateSubmitMe();
```